# Has anyone ever asked for such a boon?

Tags: scripture, vedas, puranas, gods, boon

I don't know if this question suits this site or not or whether it's a stupid question but I want to know that has there been any incident in scriptures where someone asks god for a boon that is as follows:

''Hey god I want to become Parabrahman just like you. Grant me one of the positions of parabrahman like Shiva, Vishnu, etc. or make me a separate deity.(not like a devata)''

Is there anything mentioned about this? I have also heard something regarding Purushamedha and Sarvamedha Yagnas in this context. What role do they have here?

Comment: It seems that you are asking about sayujya, sarupya, samipya & salokya mukti. Yes, it's possible. Brahmavaivarta Purana sepeaks of a sage who attained sayujya by the grace of Krishna. Devibhagavata Purana speaks of a sinner obtaining Shiva-sarupya due to effect of Rudraksha. Kalika Purana speaks of Bhagavati Adyashakti granting Mahishasura Her samipya. Limited salokya is the most common type of mukti discussed in the Puranas. Advaita seeks Brahma-sayujya. Dvaita downplays sayujya & stresses on samipya.

Comment: @AnubrataBit No I'm not asking about that. Umm..I am asking like..has a person X ever asked to replace himself with Lord Narayana or Shiva to become god Or altogether to make him a new Parabrahma apart from what we have at present.

Comment: @LSSJBroly I'm not sure if anyone has, but think about the logic of the question. If you asked to become your cat, then you would become your cat in every way. You would have the mind of your cat. You would essentially be your cat. So, if someone asked to be Parabrahman, what would change? Sometimes it is useful to see these more as roles or positions rather than specific individuals.